# Creating a Dictionary<string, T> from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Within the appsettings.json file of my ASP.NET Core Web API, I have this section, which is essentially an array of Key/Value pairs with a string key and an Environment class value:

```
  "Environments": [
    {
      "Sandbox": {
        "clientID": "",
        "secret": "",
        "adminLoginName": "",
        "apiEndpoint": "",
        "linkURL": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "Development": {
        "clientID": "",
        "secret": "",
        "adminLoginName": "",
        "apiEndpoint": "",
        "linkURL": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "Production": {
        "clientID": "",
        "secret": "",
        "adminLoginName": "",
        "apiEndpoint": "",
        "linkURL": ""
      }
    }
  ]
```

I also have this section and value for specifying which environment is currently in use:

```
  "ActiveEnvironment": "Sandbox",
```

My Environment class is defined as this:

```
public class Environment
{
    public string? ClientID { get; set; }
    public string? Secret { get; set; }
    public string? AdminLoginName { get; set; }
    public string? ApiEndpoint { get; set; }
    public string? LinkURL { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get the Environment object from the `Dictionary` of `Environment` objects based on the `Key` specified by `ActiveEnvironment`.

I got as far as using this:

`Dictionary<string, MyAPI.Models.Environment> environments = configurationSection.GetChildren().ToDictionary()` but then got totally lost in how to convert the appsettings JSON into a `<string, Environment>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy way. Simplify your json;

```json
  "Environments": 
    {
      "Sandbox": {
        "clientID": "",
        "secret": "",
        "adminLoginName": "",
        "apiEndpoint": "",
        "linkURL": ""
      },
      "Development": {
        "clientID": "",
        "secret": "",
        "adminLoginName": "",
        "apiEndpoint": "",
        "linkURL": ""
      },
      "Production": {
        "clientID": "",
        "secret": "",
        "adminLoginName": "",
        "apiEndpoint": "",
        "linkURL": ""
      }
    }
```

Then you might introduce a new configuration type and use an `IOptions<>` dependency;

```cs
public class Environments : Dictionary<string, Environment> {}

services.Configure<Environments>(configuration.GetSection("Environments"));

public class Service{
    public Service(IOptions<Environments> env){
        ... env.Value;
    }
}
```

Though if you only care about the active environment, you could skip a few steps;

```cs
var activeEnv = configuration["ActiveEnvironment"];
services.Configure<Environment>(configuration.GetSection("Environments").GetSection(activeEnv));

public class Service{
    public Service(IOptions<Environment> env){
        ... env.Value;
    }
}
```

Adding all environment values into a single file is quite unusual. The [usual pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is to split configuration into multiple files. With `appsettings.json` containing default values. Then `appsettings.{envronment}.json` overriding only those values which are different. But there might be other reasons why you would need to load a `Dictionary<>`.

Comment: I created the new class `public class Environments: Dictionary<string, MyAPI.Models.Environment> { };`, added the new configuration type: `builder.Services.Configure<MyAPI.Models.Environments>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Environments"));` but how do I use it? My DI into the cshtml.cs code behind only includes IConfiguration.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the IOptions, but I will also look at your suggestion on using multiple configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary you can set:

```
Dictionary<string, MyAPI.Models.Environment> environments =  new Dictionary();
```

and then add the data:

```
environments["development"] = your_specific_environment;
```

so from a `Dictionary` contains n elements. If you don't know the number of elements of course you can globe this inside a foreach and change the key.

```
environments[key] = value;
```

but If I could change it I would use a `List<Environment>` and "Sandbox", "Development" and so on will be a property inside the class Environment but you have to change your json.